# Finding applicable implicit conversions in Scala

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

In the Coq proof assistant - which also has implicit conversions - it is possible to search for an implicit conversion using the `SearchAbout T` command, which returns all the things which have `T` in their type (which would include conversions to or from `T`).

Is there a way of finding all conversions to or from a type for Scala programmers? Note that the conversions might be defined outside the project that defines either the source or destination type.

Comment: you want to perform such search during runtime?

Comment: @om-nom-nom No, just in e.g. Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

To just quickly see if a conversion exists in the current scope between two reference types S and T, just type

```
((null:S):T)
```

and see if it compiles. With Eclipse Scala IDE >= 2.1M2 you can see which conversion is called, if implicit highlighting is enabled in the preferences.

Of course this requires you to guess both types (but you will probably already have a clear idea of what you want to convert to and from), and it requires the conversions to already be in scope.

Comment: you also can list all implicits in the scope in scala REPL (for example, when you perform `console` command) with `:implicits [-v]`